# Maintaining IterationLevel variable?

Tags: android, variables

*Disclaimer*

This question is not a homework question, and I have tried to figure it out myself, and it is not a duplicate question.

*Disclaimer End*

Hello, I am trying to code in Android.

I am thinking of making an `IterationLevel variable = 0` at the start of the code `onCreate();`, and then afterwards, make an array and use `IterationLevel` to stroll through said array.

But when I initialized `IterationLevel` at the start (`protected void`) and tried to use it in a method, (`public/private int`) an error shows up stating that the variable is not defined. Is there something large that I am missing here?

Sample of code (target for Iteration Level)

```
private int GetGPSData() {
        IterationLevel += 1;

       //Inject values into arrays named called long and lat
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to post an example of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using global variable...  If you're using a local variable you can access it outside of the method.

Comment: Thanks! Making a global variable looks tough, but I'm sure it will work! I'll give it a try and get back to you on that.